# In pom.xml maven-antrun-plugin not found

Tags: java, reactjs, plugins, maven-3

I am following this [blog](https://medium.com/@sanjayyadav_56210/react-js-with-spring-boot-in-production-564a4ab41e64) to build my backend in spring boot and frontend in Reactjs. When I cloned the code, it is working fine. But in pom.xml it shows error message as maven-antrun-plugin not found. Why is it so? How do I fix it?

> ```
>     <plugin>
>         <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId> // error not found
>         <executions>
>            <execution>
>               <phase>generate-resources</phase>
>               <configuration>
>                  <target>
>                     <copy todir="${project.build.directory}/classes/static">
>                        <fileset dir="${project.basedir}/frontend/build" />
>                     </copy>
>                  </target>
>               </configuration>
>               <goals>
>                  <goal>run</goal>
>               </goals>
>            </execution>
>         </executions>
>      </plugin>
> ```

Comment: You can specify groupId and version also...like this...and then retry
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>

Comment: Yes, this worked fine. Thanks a lot

Comment: Np. I will post it again as answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Along with artifactId, you should specify groupId as org.apache.maven.plugins and version as 1.8